# Scala: Is it a class instance?

Tags: scala

If I run this code (see it below) I get `CaseClass` as printed message.

```
case class CaseClass(var name: String)

object Main extends App {
  val obj = CaseClass
  println(obj)
}
```

But what does it mean? I mean is `CaseClass` similar to Java's `CaseClass.class`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you define a `case class` it actually defines both a `class` AND an `object`, both with the same name.  When you say `val obj = CaseClass`, you are actually assigning the `object`, a singleton object, to `obj`.

It's kind of like:

```
class NonCaseClass(var name: String) {  // the actual class
  override def toString = "the class version" 
}
object NonCaseClass {                   // singleton companion object
  override def toString = "the object version" 
}

val obj = NonCaseClass   // this assigns the companion object to a variable
println(obj)
// the object version
```

This is different from instantiating an instance of the class `CaseClass`:

```
val obj2 = new NonCaseClass("x")
println(obj2)
// the class version
```